# :hover style on div with an image that doesnt trigger

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay, pure-css

I've been trying to make a overlay hover effect on a website with pure css

```
                       <div class="col-md-4 port-show">
                            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="">
                            <h2 class=""></h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

But I've run into the problem **when I hover over the img** that the overlay will not trigger. I know I have to do it differently, but just don't now how.
CSS:

```
:hover:after{
        content: "";
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: which element are you hovering on?

Comment: Don't think you can do an after on an image as it is placing an element at the end (inside) the element and img tags can't have child elements, also as you are positioning the after absolutely, you would have to make the img relative

Comment: @JayGhosh I was trying to hover the div, but when I'm a little too quick and hover over the image, then my hover effect doesn't work.

Comment: `I'm a little too quick and hover over the image`. That depends on your browser's capability to capture the hover event bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look here. Maybe this solution will be helpfull for you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKmxZw

```css
.img-holder {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
}
.img-holder img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-holder:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.img-holder:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 port-show">
  <span class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </span>
  <h2 class=""></h2>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Pete, I believe this might have solved my conundrum :D

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this and make your overlay effect

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  color: #c55;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  background: url("http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/fog-forest-haze-4827-524x350.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container:hover .overlay span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1.3s ease;
  transition: 1.3s ease;
}
.container .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
.container .overlay span {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Overlay Hover Effect</h2>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span>Click to see more...</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Some easy overlay code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
  .pic{ width:190px;
   height:190px; opacity: 1; 
   filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
   background: url(http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/duck.png) no-repeat; }
   .pic:hover { opacity: 0.3; filter: alpha(opacity=30);}
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="pic">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```